Redbean returning boolean columns as string
I am having a problem using Redbean. I have a table photos having the photos definition:
+----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field          | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id             | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| account_number | varchar(20) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| photo          | text        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| isDefault      | tinyint(1)  | YES  |     | 0       |                |
+----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

I have a small PHP script:
    <?php

        require 'rbconnect.php';
        $photos = R::findOne('photos');
        var_dump($photos);
        $photos->id = intval($photos->id);
        $photos->isDefault = intval($photos->isDefault);
        echo json_encode($photos);
?>

First part of returned result var_dump($photos):
object(RedBeanPHP\OODBBean)#17 (11) {
  ["properties":protected]=>
  array(4) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["account_number"]=>
    string(10) "1234567890"
    ["photo"]=>
    string(17) "sample_photo_data"
    ["isDefault"]=>
    string(1) "0"
  }
  ["__info":protected]=>
  array(8) {
    ["type"]=>
    string(6) "photos"
    ["sys.id"]=>
    string(2) "id"
    ["sys.orig"]=>
    array(4) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["account_number"]=>
      string(10) "1234567890"
      ["photo"]=>
      string(17) "sample_photo_data"
      ["isDefault"]=>
      string(1) "0"
    }
    ["tainted"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["changed"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["changelist"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["model"]=>
    NULL
    ["data.bundle"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
  ["beanHelper":protected]=>
  object(RedBeanPHP\BeanHelper\SimpleFacadeBeanHelper)#13 (0) {
  }
  ["fetchType":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["withSql":protected]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["withParams":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["aliasName":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["via":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["noLoad":protected]=>
  bool(false)
  ["all":protected]=>
  bool(false)
  ["castProperty":protected]=>
  NULL
}

Second part of the returned json is:
{"id":1,"account_number":"1234567890","photo":"sample_photo_data","isDefault":"0","is_default":0} 

I am having two ambiguities:

If I do not do a casting both id and isDefault returned type is String, are not they supposed to be of type int?
Casting is working for id but not for isDefault. When casting isDefault, it is instead recreating another column is_default.


var_dump($photos) after performing query and see what you have there.

@u_mulder, added that to the question

This is a temporary solution I am using, until someone post a better one.
$photo is an object created by RedBean so it is probably not allowing the modification of its attributes.
To be able to cast the attributes, I am simply recreating an object:
$newPhoto = json_decode(json_encode($photo));
$newPhoto->isDefault = intval($newPhoto->isDefault);

result is:
{"id":1,"account_number":"1234567890","photo":"sample_photo_data","isDefault":0} 

